# Django with Javascript fetch API: POST works but all other unsafe methods are forbidden

Tags: django, http-post, fetch-api, http-method, http-put

I am working on this [CS50W project](https://cs50.harvard.edu/web/2020/projects/4/network/).

When using the fetch API to send `POST` requests to the server, everything worked fine.
After I changed the method to `PUT`, or any other unsafe methods, things stopped working.

Javascript

```
let like_form = document.querySelector('#like-form');
let data = new FormData(like_form);

fetch(`post/${post_id}/like`, {
  method: 'POST',
  body: data,
  credentials: "same-origin"
})
```

views.py

```
@login_required
def like_post(request, post_id):

    if request.method == 'POST':
        post = get_post(post_id)
        if post:
            if request.user in post.liked_by.all():
                post.liked_by.remove(request.user)
                status = False
            else:
                post.liked_by.add(request.user)
                status = True
            
            return JsonResponse({
                'message': 'Success.',
                'status': status
            }, status=200)
```

index.html

```
<form id='like-form'>
    {% csrf_token %}
</form>
```

Output using `POST`

`{message: 'Success.', status: false}`

Output using `PUT`

```
PUT http://127.0.0.1:8000/post/17/like 403 (Forbidden)
Forbidden (CSRF token missing.): /post/17/like
```

The only thing I changed was the `method` in `fetch` and views.py

Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After going into the [source code](https://github.com/django/django/blob/main/django/middleware/csrf.py), I found out that for `PUT`, the `csrf_token` is read from the `headers` of the request instead of the body. Therefore adding

```
headers: {
  'x-csrftoken': CSRF_TOKEN_ELEMENT.value
}
```

solved the problem